# Any alternatives to proftpd and vsftpd that is easier to configure?

Tags: centos, ftp

I tried them both, I'm having troubles to configure them,so is there a third one that is easier to install and configure?

I'm using centos 5 64 bit xen vps

for example I'm following [this tutorial](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/pf-firewall-open-ftp-port-21/), it says: Append following two config directive to setup ftp port ranges:

```
pasv_min_port=49152
pasv_max_port=65535
```

but i cannot find the ports to append them and i don't want to open port 21, I want to open a port like 538, I know how but I can't fix the first problem

the configuration is not working, I'm looking for an easier to install and configure alternative, do you know any?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Vsftpd is very easy to configure. I think your difficulty is because you're confusing a port range configuration for passive FTP with the listening port for the command channel (what normally runs on port 21.) Give this document a once-over to see what I mean: http://slacksite.com/other/ftp.html

The configuration option you're looking for in vsftpd.conf to change the command port from 21 to 538 is "listen_port". See the configuration documentation on your system ("man vsftpd.conf") or here: http://vsftpd.beasts.org/vsftpd_conf.html

Comment: To configure proftpd is even easier. But these kind of questions are stupid questions. There is no "magic-magic-FTPd" that interprets what a user wants and configures itself. Configuration is always needed or the next question would be: "Why is easyftpd so unflexible?"

Comment: I have always wondered whether these passive port opening should be considered as a security risk to be exploited by a potential hacker. Can anyone shed some light?